# Can not determine the file type from file content using Node.js

Tags: node.js, buffer, file-type

I can not check the what is the file type from file content. I am explaining my code below.

```
const FileType = require('file-type');
let content = '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';
let stepsRawData = Buffer.from(content, 'base64');
await isFileType(stepsRawData);

isFileType = async (buffer) => {

    try{
        console.log('filetype',await FileType.fromBuffer(buffer));
    }catch(err) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here I am using `file-type` module to check what is the file type. I have some `base64` encoded file content and I need to check what type(`i.e- json/xml/txt`) of file content this. But as per my code this console message is showing `filetype undefined`. Here I need to determine the file type from encoded file content.Can any body help me to fix this problem ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type#supported-file-types base64 is not there in the list

Comment: I know what is my requirement. my file content in `base64` ecoded format and I need to check the file type from this.

Comment: convert back to base 10 / utf8 and then pass it to FileType.fromBuffer

Comment: Can you please post your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
isFileType = async (buffer) => {
  try {
      console.log('filetype', await FileType.fromBuffer(Buffer.from(buffer, 'base64')));
  } catch(err) {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, I am doing `let stepsRawData = Buffer.from(content, 'base64');` for decoding means I can direct pass the `content` ??

Comment: I changes as per you but same issue.

Comment: ok your data is clearly in JSON but the library does not recognize json... surround JSON.parse() in a try catch to check if json or not

Comment: Thats true but also I have some content which are `xml and txt`. Here actually my requirement is I have some encoded file content in array and I need to check `json/xml/txt` content those are.

Comment: use try catch to check if json, if not json then use FileType.fromBuffer() to check if xml. if not xml then by process of elimination it is txt

Comment: I following same but thing is for xml enocded content also its returning undefined.